# How to set default font for 'cursive' font-family in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm tweaking with fonts settings in Google Chrome.

Youtube provides 'cursive' and 'fantasy' as a font-family option for its captions.

So, I was trying to find a way to change the settings for default fonts set for 'fantasy' and 'cursive', but I couldn't find one.

While Advanced Font Settings offer a quite wide range of choices, it does not have an option for setting default font for 'cursive' and 'fantasy'.

Though I believe chromium provides a way to change them (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings), I can't figure out how to do it.

So, is there any way to change fonts set for 'cursive' and 'fantasy' in chrome?

P.S.

This question is similar to

https://superuser.com/questions/737965/how-do-i-choose-which-font-chrome-uses-for-cursive-and-fantasy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

I'm adding this link for a case my explanation is inapprehensible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should install [Advanced Font Settings](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm) extension. then, open option page by right-click font icon(or navigate to `chrome-extension://caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm/options.html`)

open developer console at options page and paste below codes to change default font. locale codes can be found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings#type-ScriptCode

```
chrome.fontSettings.setFont(
    { genericFamily: 'cursive', script: 'Zyyy', fontId: '(font nane to change)' }
);
```

(change default global cursive font)

```
chrome.fontSettings.setFont(
    { genericFamily: 'cursive', script: 'Hang', fontId: '(font nane to change)' }
);
```

(change default Korean cursive font)

to change fantasy font, simply replace `cursive` with `fantasy`